# How to write to static file in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm making an example to write to static file (.txt).

I've tried:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string dt = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");

        string path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, $"Logs/{dt}");

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        string filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, $"Logs/{dt}/{dt}.txt");

        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            AddText(fs, "foo");
            AddText(fs, "bar\tbaz");
        }

        return View();
    }

    private void AddText(FileStream fs, string value)
    {
        byte[] info = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(value);
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
```

But it created everything inside `wwwroot` folder instead of the root of project.

[image: 1]

I want to create the text file here:

[image: 2]

Where can I edit?

**UPDATE:**

This is how I define `_environment`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well isn't `_environment.WebRootPath` giving you the path to `wwwroot` here?

Comment: replace `Logs/{dt}` with `../Logs/{dt}`

Comment: @Lashane Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lashane That assumes you are keeping the default wwwroot folder of course.

Comment: @DavidG that assumes structure OP provided

Comment: @Lashane Or you just use `ContentRootPath` instead of `WebRootPath` and avoid any confusion at all.

Comment: @DavidG yes, if ContentRootPath and WebRootPath are not overriden, then contentrootpath is parent of webroot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using [`IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_WebRootPath) to determine the root folder. This property is the absolute path to the directory that contains the web-servable application content files - i.e. the `wwwroot` folder. Instead you should use the [`IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_ContentRootPath) property which will give you the absolute path to the directory that contains the application.

For example:

```
var contentRoot = _environment.ContentRootPath;
var webRoot = _environment.WebRootPath;

//contentRoot = "C:\Projects\YourWebApp"
//webRoot     = "C:\Projects\YourWebApp\wwwroot"
```

You could use `WebRootPath` and navigate to it's parent directory, but if for some reason you choose to move `wwwroot` somewhere else, your code may break. Much better to use a method that will give you the correct path every time in every project.

Comment: Thanks for classifying. I've just tested. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, $"Logs/{dt}/{dt}.txt");
```

use

```
var folder = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(_environment.WebRootpath).Parent.FullName;
var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, $"Logs/{dt}/{dt}.txt");
```

Comment: Oops, should be `DirectoryInfo`. Edited.